# Steam doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, games, steam

I've been trying to play a recently purchased game and, when Play button is clicked, suddenly a random message appears along with the Cancel and Stop buttons instead of Play. But this happens so quick, and it's in Play again. I can't read the message, even recording it in video. I've tried uninstalling Steam and installing it again, and some mysterious commands that I found in some forums, but none of that worked. What else can I do? If you need more information about mi computer just ask.

Comment: Does steam itself work? Your question sounds like a specific game doesn't work. If that is the case, you'll probably get better answers in the steam community forums or, if it is a game running via proton, on winehq.

Comment: Hi @danzel. Yes, Steam works. I didn't try other game yet because I didn't think it can be the problem of a specific game. I'll try now.

Comment: @danzel ok, one game is working so I understand it's the particular game's problem. Thanks.